# Как избавиться от дублированного react`а? ( Invalid hook call )

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

При использований библиотек (я пробовал `styledcomponents` и `react-router`) в react приложений появляется ошибка:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of >a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as >React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug >and fix this problem.

Перейдя по ссылке и прочитав документацию - решил, что у меня почему то несколько версий react или что то типа того, так как проделав данный пункт:

```
// Добавьте это в файл node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

//Добавьте это в ваш файл с компонентом
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

//Если код выше выводит false, то у вас может быть две версии React,
//а значит требуется выяснить, как это произошло. 
//Данное ишью (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) 
//содержит некоторые распространённые причины, обнаруженные сообществом.
```

Вот сам код:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import AboutPage from './pages/aboutpage';
import BlogPage from './pages/blogPage';

function App() {

require('react-dom');            //Проверил react на дублирование 
window.React2 = require('react'); //как указано в документаций (смотреть выше)
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <header>
          <a href = '/'>Home</a>
          <a href = '/posts'>Posts</a>
          <a href = '/about'>About</a>
        </header>
      </div>
     </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Ошибка вылезает сразу после того, как я использую `<Route></Route>`

node_modules/react-dom/index.js (путь из документаций)

```
'use strict';
function checkDCE() {
  if (
    typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'undefined' ||
    typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.checkDCE !== 'function'
  ) {
    return;
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    throw new Error('^_^');
  }
  try {
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.checkDCE(checkDCE);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  checkDCE();
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react-dom.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react-dom.development.js');
}

window.React1 = require('react');     //Добавил судя по документаций
```

У меня вышло `false`. После перехода по ссылке с решением от сообщества я если честно не понял ни одного решения,
может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой и может мне помочь? Сижу уже два дня, ничего не могу сделать, помогите пожалуйста, ну вот ничего поделать не могу :(

Comment: Ты какую-то дичь творишь...

Comment: Что именно? Я шаги по документаций вроде делаю, вон ссылка в самом посте на неё